# Why am I getting duplicate records from this method when I parse XML?

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, jaxb, stax

I'm trying to parse content from XML using Stax. To create an object from it and place it in the list. I created the `parseXml()` method for that but if the element country has more than two element users, it always duplicates the last one.

The method I used is this one:

```
public static List<User> parseXML() {
    List<User> empList = new ArrayList<>();
    User emp = null;
    XMLInputFactory xmlInputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
    try {
        XMLEventReader xmlEventReader = xmlInputFactory.createXMLEventReader(new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\untitled1\\src\\main\\xml\\users.xml"));
        while(xmlEventReader.hasNext()){
            XMLEvent xmlEvent = xmlEventReader.nextEvent();
            if (xmlEvent.isStartElement()){
                StartElement startElement = xmlEvent.asStartElement();
                if(startElement.getName().getLocalPart().equals("country")){
                    emp = new User();
                    //Get the 'id' attribute from Employee element
                    Attribute idAttr = startElement.getAttributeByName(new QName("name"));
                    if(idAttr != null){
                        emp.setCountry(idAttr.getValue());
                    }
                }
                //set the other varibles from xml elements
                else if(startElement.getName().getLocalPart().equals("first_name")){
                    xmlEvent = xmlEventReader.nextEvent();
                    emp.setFirst_name(xmlEvent.asCharacters().getData());
                }else if(startElement.getName().getLocalPart().equals("last_name")){
                    xmlEvent = xmlEventReader.nextEvent();
                    emp.setLast_name(xmlEvent.asCharacters().getData());
                }else if(startElement.getName().getLocalPart().equals("address")){
                    xmlEvent = xmlEventReader.nextEvent();
                    emp.setAddress(xmlEvent.asCharacters().getData());
                }else if(startElement.getName().getLocalPart().equals("city")){
                    xmlEvent = xmlEventReader.nextEvent();
                    emp.setCity(xmlEvent.asCharacters().getData());
                }else if(startElement.getName().getLocalPart().equals("email")){
                    xmlEvent = xmlEventReader.nextEvent();
                    emp.setEmail(xmlEvent.asCharacters().getData());
                }
            }
            //if Employee end element is reached, add employee object to list
            if(xmlEvent.isEndElement()){
                EndElement endElement = xmlEvent.asEndElement();
                if(endElement.getName().getLocalPart().equals("user")){
                    empList.add(emp);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException | XMLStreamException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return empList;
}
```

Here is XML:

```
<data>
    <continent name="Europe">
        <country name="United Kingdom">
            <!-- Users -->
            <user>
                <first_name>John</first_name>
                <last_name>Smith</last_name>
                <address>320 Regent Street</address>
                <city>London</city>
                <email>john.smith@gmail.com</email>
                <password>skek3E5k</password>
            </user>
            <user>
                <first_name>Michael</first_name>
                <last_name>Smith</last_name>
                <address>322 Regent Street</address>
                <city>London</city>
                <email>michael.smith@hotmail.com</email>
                <password>gk3288skW</password>
            </user>
        </country>
        <country name="Germany">
            <!-- Users -->
            <user>
                <first_name>Max</first_name>
                <last_name>Mustermann</last_name>
                <address>Berlinerstrasse 7</address>
                <city>Hamburg</city>
                <email>mmustermann@yahoo.com</email>
                <password>kdkei44229</password>
            </user>
          </country>
    </continent>
    <continent name="North America">
        <country name="United States">
            <!-- Users -->
            <user>
                <first_name>Julia</first_name>
                <last_name>Johnson</last_name>
                <address>300 Boylston Ave E</address>
                <city>Seattle</city>
                <email>julia.johnson@gmail.com</email>
                <password>49dksSSe3</password>
            </user>
        </country>
    </continent>
</data>
```

What am I doing wrong in my method?

Answer (score 0):

You create an instance of `User` only when you encounter a `<country>`, but each country may have more the one user. You end up adding the same `User` object for every user in the country.

I think the confusion may come from the fact that you are effectively adding references to `emp` to your `empList`—hence, when you change `emp` for your second, third, etc. user in  a given country, you change the same `User` object that is already in the list.

You should probably be creating your `User` object each time you encounter a `<user>` tag. This will require, however, that you also store the current country. Your code could look something like this:

```
public static List<User> parseXML() {
        List<User> empList = new ArrayList<>();
        User emp = null;
        XMLInputFactory xmlInputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
        try {
            XMLEventReader xmlEventReader = xmlInputFactory.createXMLEventReader(new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\untitled1\\src\\main\\xml\\users.xml"));
            String country = null;
            while(xmlEventReader.hasNext()){
                XMLEvent xmlEvent = xmlEventReader.nextEvent();
                if (xmlEvent.isStartElement()){
                    StartElement startElement = xmlEvent.asStartElement();
                    if(startElement.getName().getLocalPart().equals("country")){
                        //Get the 'id' attribute from Employee element
                        Attribute idAttr = startElement.getAttributeByName(new QName("name"));
                        if(idAttr != null){
                            country = idAttr.getValue();
                        }
                    }
                    else if (startElement.getName().getLocalPart().equals("user")) {
                        emp = new User();
                        emp.setCountry(country);
                    }
                    //set the other varibles from xml elements
                    else if(startElement.getName().getLocalPart().equals("first_name")){
                        xmlEvent = xmlEventReader.nextEvent();
                        emp.setFirst_name(xmlEvent.asCharacters().getData());
                    }else if(startElement.getName().getLocalPart().equals("last_name")){
                        xmlEvent = xmlEventReader.nextEvent();
                        emp.setLast_name(xmlEvent.asCharacters().getData());
                    }else if(startElement.getName().getLocalPart().equals("address")){
                        xmlEvent = xmlEventReader.nextEvent();
                        emp.setAddress(xmlEvent.asCharacters().getData());
                    }else if(startElement.getName().getLocalPart().equals("city")){
                        xmlEvent = xmlEventReader.nextEvent();
                        emp.setCity(xmlEvent.asCharacters().getData());
                    }else if(startElement.getName().getLocalPart().equals("email")){
                        xmlEvent = xmlEventReader.nextEvent();
                        emp.setEmail(xmlEvent.asCharacters().getData());
                    }
                }
                //if Employee end element is reached, add employee object to list
                if(xmlEvent.isEndElement()){
                    EndElement endElement = xmlEvent.asEndElement();
                    if(endElement.getName().getLocalPart().equals("user")){
                        empList.add(emp);
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException | XMLStreamException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return empList;
    }
```